# How can I change the data of file property in .slddrw file?

Tags: python, macros, solidworks

There is a menu where the properties can be accessed and modified, such as who drew the drawing file and when it was created etc. You can also add more properties.

More about file properties:

http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/t_properties_fundamentals.htm

**My purpose is to modify a property value with python on an existing file with a macro or something like that.**

I know that for these things is the best choice would be VB/C# but I am familiar just with python. I have read about python macros for solidworks but these informations weren't clear for me :/.

Comment: SolidWorks files are in a proprietary format. Reverse-engineering the format is likely to difficult irrespective of whether you choose to do it in Python, VB, or C#.

Comment: I dont want to change the format, just modify some things in the file

Comment: I didn't say you wanted to change the format. But you want to read the file, change stuff, and save it back. That means your program has to *understand* the format. To achieve that you're going to have to reverse-engineer the format, because it is proprietary. That may be very difficult.

Comment: Yes it would be difficult but with VB/C# it is easy because there is an API for that, I dont know what is with python.

Answer (score 1):

To call the SolidWorks COM API from Python, you need the Python equivalent of this VB:

```
Dim swApp As Object
Set swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")
```

Fortunately, this is not hard. Install `win32com`, which you can download from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32. You can then call the SolidWorks COM API from Python like this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
swApp=Dispatch("SldWorks.Application")
```

After that you can do anything from Python with `swApp` that the API would let you do in VB. The variable `swApp` is a thin Python wrapper around a COM object that will behave exactly the same as in VB. I see that there is an API manual of around 250 pages. You will of course have to transpose the VB examples into Python syntax.